# stereo camera calibration error

Tags: stereo-3d, opencv, calibration, python

I am trying to perform a stereo calibration of 2 USB cameras in order to perform depth map, but I fall on this error and I don't know how to solve. 
I would be really grateful to who would be able to help.

```
 File "C:/Users/gaetano/stereoCalib.py", line 85, in <module>
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, 
gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

error: OpenCV(3.4.1) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv- 
3.4.1\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3384: error: (-215) nimages > 0 in 
function cv::calibrateCamera

(this error should have been solved using the following code) 



#before here i have collect picture from both the camera, than 
#grey conversion
i=0
while i < img_counter:
img = cv2.imread('colorRight_' + str(i) + '.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('colorLeft_' + str(i) + '.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imwrite('greyRight_' + str(i) + '.jpg',gray)
cv2.imwrite('greyLeft_' + str(i) + '.jpg',gray2)
i += 1 



nx = 9
ny = 6
chess_imagesL = glob.glob('greyLeft_*.jpg')
chess_imagesR = glob.glob('greyRight_*.jpg')
for i in range(len(chess_imagesL)):
# Read in the image
chess_board_imageL = mpimg.imread(chess_imagesL[i])
chess_board_imageR = mpimg.imread(chess_imagesR[i])
# Convert to grayscale
# gray = cv2.cvtColor(chess_board_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
# Find the chessboard corners
ret, cornersL = cv2.findChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageL, (nx, ny), 
None)
ret2, cornersR = cv2.findChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageR, (nx, ny), 
None)
# If found, draw corners
if ret == True:
    # Draw and display the corners
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageL, (nx, ny), cornersL, ret)
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageR, (nx, ny), cornersR, ret2)
    result_nameL = 'boardL'+str(i)+'.png'
    result_nameR = 'boardR'+str(i)+'.png'
    cv2.imwrite(result_nameL, chess_board_imageL)
    cv2.imwrite(result_nameR, chess_board_imageR)

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

## prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpointsL=[]
objpointsR=[]
imgpointsL=[]
imgpointsR=[]  


for i in range(len(chess_imagesL)):
# Read in the image
chess_board_imageL = mpimg.imread(chess_imagesL[i])
chess_board_imageR = mpimg.imread(chess_imagesR[i])

ret, cornersL = cv2.findChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageL, (nx, ny), 
None)
ret2, cornersR = cv2.findChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageR, (nx, ny), 
None)
# If found, draw corners
if ret == True:
    objpointsL.append(objp)
    objpointsR.append(objp)

    corners2L = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,cornersL,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
    corners2R = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,cornersR,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)

    imgpointsL.append(corners2L)
    imgpointsR.append(corners2R)



    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageL, (nx, ny), corners2L, ret)
    cv2.drawChessboardCorners(chess_board_imageR, (nx, ny), corners2R, ret2)
    result_nameL = 'boardL'+str(i)+'.png'
    result_nameR = 'boardR'+str(i)+'.png'
    cv2.imwrite(result_nameL, chess_board_imageL)
    cv2.imwrite(result_nameR, chess_board_imageR)
```

## the part which gives problems

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpointsL, imgpointsL, 
gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
ret2, mtx2, dist2, rvecs2, tvecs2 = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpointsR, 
imgpointsR, gray2.shape[::-1], None, None)
R = []
T = []
E = []
F = []
flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
ret, mtx, dist, mtx2, dist2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpointsL, 
imgpointsL ,imgpointsR, mtx, dist, mtx2, dist2, gray.shape[::-1], None, 
None, None, None,flags = flags,
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 30, 1e-6))
```

## UPDATE the error in  cv2.solvePnP

using the code you suggested, cameracalibration seems to work. but i have a problem on the next step, stereocameracalibration

File "C:/Users/gaetano/Desktop/sonido/CALIPROVA2.py", line 157, in 
ret, R, T = cv2.solvePnP(objpointsL,imgpointsL,mtx,dist,R,T,0,0)

TypeError: objectPoints is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

```
R = []
T = []
E = []
F = []
flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC

ret, mtx, dist, mtx2, dist2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpointsL, 
imgpointsL ,imgpointsR, mtxL, distL, mtxR, distR,
grayL.shape[::-1], None, None, None, None,
flags = flags,
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 30, 1e-6))



ret, R, T = cv2.solvePnP(objpointsL,imgpointsL,mtx,dist,R,T,0,0)
print(R)
print(T)
```

## resizing

error in resizing
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

```
print(roi1)
print(roi2)
# crop the image
x, y, w, h = roi1
dst = dst[y:y + h, x:x + w]
#
dst2 = dst2[y:y + h, x:x + w]
dst = cv2.resize(dst, 0, dst, 2, 2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Comment: you have empty `objpoints` the line where you append somethin to it is commented

Comment: thanks for your answer, but even uncommenting the line, the error is there

Comment: I think solvepnp takes one set of points, so maybe something like objpointsL[0] and imgpointsL[0] will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error says:

> error: OpenCV(3.4.1)
>   D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.1\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3384:
>   error: (-215) nimages > 0 in function cv::calibrateCamera

This means that you are passing empty list variables as the object points or as the image points.

In your code you have:

```
objpoints=[]
imgpoints=[]
```

which are then used only in the line:

```
#objpoints.append(objp)
```

and in the line:

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

This means that both are empty! nothing is inside those 2 lists that are then used in the function. In the next line:

```
ret2, mtx2, dist2, rvecs2, tvecs2 = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints2, gray2.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

Here you use `imgpoints2` which exists and has point, but it has no objpoints (because it is commented out) and you will get a similar error.

Solution:

You have to make up your mind of what exactly you want to achieve here. If it is 2 calibrations, then maybe a function that takes a frame as input and does all the process will be better. This way you are sure that the variables are named correctly.

If a function is not good for you, then you can always do the same that you did for `imgpoints2` to `imgpoints` and the variable will be able to be use. Also, make sure that `objpoints.append(objp)` is uncommented to get the function working again.

Just for sake of completeness, this is what i mean with the funciton:

```
def getObjPoints():
  objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
  objp[:,:2]=np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
  return objp

def calibrateCamWithFrame( frame ):
  objpoints=[getObjPoints]
  imgpoints=[]
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray,(7,6),None)
  # if no corners where found return None
  if !ret:
    return None
  criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
  corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
  imgpoints.append(corners)
  frameWithCorners=cv2.drawChessboardCorners(frame,(7,6), corners, ret)
  cv2.imshow('img',frameWithCorners)
  cv2.waitKey(500)
  return cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

Then from outside you will just call:

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = calibrateCamWithFrame(frame)
ret2, mtx2, dist2, rvecs2, tvecs2 = calibrateCamWithFrame(frame2)
```

**UPDATE**

Since you wanted is to calibrate 2 cameras, and did appropriate changes to the code to identify it, then the solution is to read image, find corners and appending data in the main loop. Something like:

```
nx = 9
ny = 6
imgpointsL = []
imgpointsR = []
objpointsL = []
objpointsR = []
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

for i in range(img_counter):
  grayR = cv2.imread('colorRight_' + str(i) + '.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )
  grayL = cv2.imread('colorLeft_' + str(i) + '.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )

  retR, cornersR = cv2.findChessboardCorners(grayR, (nx, ny), None)
  if retR:
     cornersR = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, cornersR, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
     imgpointsR.append(cornersR)
     objpointsR.append(objp)

  retL, cornersL = cv2.findChessboardCorners(grayL, (nx, ny), None)

  if retL:
     cornersL = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, cornersL, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
     imgpointsL.append(cornersR)
     objpointsL.append(objp)
```

And now you can calibrate each camera, note that I use imgpoints and objpoints for each camera... This way you are sure the sizes match, since not necessarily all the images in one camera will have the corners found correctly.

Then you can calibrate, making sure you have images:

```
  if len(imgpointsL) >0:
    retL, mtxL, distL, rvecsL, tvecsL = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpointsL, imgpointsL,grayL.shape[::-1], None, None)

  if len(imgpointsL) >0:
    retR, mtxR, distR, rvecsR, tvecsR = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpointsR, imgpointsR,grayR.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

Comment: thanks for the help you are giving. Just one question. If i don't use the function, i have to put the imgpoint acquisition in a loop?

Comment: @gaetanoma I am not sure what exactly is your goal... but I guess you want to use ALL the images in just one calibration calculation (which is the typical case), right? I put the function because you were doing 2 times the same code... but normally you should find the corners in the loop and if found append the points to imgpoint and the objpoints add another objp (so they match in size) I can update the answer if that is what you are aiming...

Comment: yes exactly. i have take picture from 2 cameras, than i save picture, convert to grey and draw the cheessboard. My intention is first do the calibration of both the single cameras, and than to perform a stereocalibration. i've changed my code, so you can see what i do in the first post

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, i think to be arrived to a solution putting everything in the loop.
but now i have another problem because cv2.calibrateCamera works, but i have an error in
    R = []
    T = []
    E = []
    F = []
    flags = cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
    ret, R, T = cv2.solvePnP(objpointsL,imgpointsL,mtx,dist,R,T,0,0)


it says objpoints is not numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: @gaetanoma I made an update to my answer :) take a look

Comment: really thank you for your big help. going over with the code i have another problem with stereocalib. I've updated the question, could you check?

Comment: sorry if i continue under the same post. could you give a look to the last update? i have a problem with resizing

Comment: @gaetanoma It is better to do another question rather than add more problems to the same question. This way it is clear for anyone who enters what is the solution of the question and other people may answer it faster. The problem is that you passed 0 to size when size is a tuple e.g. (0,0)